# app does not load engine's assets via sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets, rails-engines

I am trying to rewrite an app using rails 3.1 making use of engines.
Somehow the test dummy app does not pick up my assets and I don't know what would be causing this. i.e. stylesheets from the engine are are not included, same for javascript, and probably every thing else.

Anyone mind to have a look at https://github.com/janlimpens/portfolio-engine?

Comment: I tested you engine and couldn't find out what's wrong. Could you describe your problem more precisely (would be even better with the steps to reproduce)?

Comment: I think I understand what he's going through. The Dummy app might not be loading the javascripts correctly when running specs tests with capybara....at least that's what I have encountered.

Comment: Somehow this went away and I don't recall, what exactly I did. I think I created a new rails plugin and copied over the essential parts of the old engine.